# iOS IAP - How to distinguish "restoring done, but not purchased before" state

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

How can I distiguish the condition when a user is hitting restore but has never bought that IAP package before.

When I trigger

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

the system triggers the following callbacks

1) For an already-bought item those 2 in that order

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
```

2) For an not-yet-bought item simply

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
```

With this possible combinations, how can I ensure / verify that the call 'restore' was called, but the result is "not yet bought".

Do I really have to save the state "*paymentQueue was not yet called and now paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished was called*" as condition?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is process any purchases that are delivered to `updatedTransactions` as you do for the initial purchase case. Ie. unlock content or provide additional functions and persist the purchase in keychain or whatever method you are using.

`paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` lets you know that the restore operation is complete. You can use this method to update your UI if required. For example if you showed an activity indicator when you started restoring then you can use this callback to remove that indicator.

Comment: okay, but what it i want to tell the user "sorry, could not restore because you did not buy yet". `updateTransactions` will not be triggered and `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` does not provide any information about success or failure

Comment: Then you can check your "purchased" state from keychain or whatever in `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` and display the message if it is false